# Making a small, clickable box in the corner of an input cell that shows a pop-up list on click.

Tags: javascript, html, popup, user-input

I am currently making a Sudoku board, and I'm planning on making a clickable-number list which the player can click on to enter the number value instead of having to enter numbers using the keyboard.

My cells right now are formatted as such:

```
<div class="board">
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="row2">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
...
```

These cells are the standard cells you would expect of a Sudoku game, and currently I can input numbers into them.

How would I go about adding a small box in the top-right corner of these cells, that I can click on?(on click, it will show a popup menu, but that is not the point of this question, so I will research that later).

I thought maybe I should add div tags within the cells with class "corner box" or something and css it to make it go to the top right. But wouldn't this interfere when I click on the cells to input values?

I add inputs into the cells as such:

```
$cell.html('<input type="text"/>').find('input').focus();
```

So having a div tag within the cell div would be weird.

Comment: what about using a small image/icon?

Comment: The question is, how would i add this icon to the top-right corner of my cell without making it interfere when I try to input a value in the my cell.

Answer (score 0):

To add elements to a div without replacing the current content, use [append()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

```
var cell = document.getElementById('row1').children[0];
cell.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2yjfL30a/).

Comment: how would you go about adding that little box in the input field though? Or is that not possible

Comment: You'd need to do that with css.  One way would be to set the background of the input to the image url, like so:  https://jsfiddle.net/9kpyk1wz/1/